# Does any DOM implementation exist which doesn't load the entire file in at parse time?

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I've got some XML files which are larger than available memory, and a large (!) codebase that assumes it can operate on that file using a DOM structure. However, some users have reported OutOfMemoryException s on large input sizes; and the XML is larger than the address space available on 32 bit processors.

Is there a DOM implementation out there which can deal with this case, and only "hydrates" child objects as necessary in order to achieve reasonable memory use with enormous XML files?

Comment: Have you tried using `XDocument`? I don't know for certain if that's going to help, but the alternative is to use `XmlReader` and operate on nodes as they are read in.

Comment: do a search for "SAX parser C#" and you'll come up with some approaches, many of which will probably use XmlReader under the covers as Oded mentioned.

Comment: @Jim: SAX is a completely different model, which would require rewriting the entire codebase currently using DOM. (The whole point is to avoid this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [great solution outlined in a two part post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2007/03/05/streaming-with-linq-to-xml-part-2.aspx) by the MS XmlTeam for reaping the benefits of linq2xml, but streaming the file and not loading in the whole thing. After many blind alleys and dead-ends, this was the solution I settled on when reading >10GB xml files from database dumps.

Comment: +1 Streaming is the way to go. Or converting it from Xml to an binary format which can be read much faster without any parsing.

Answer (score 1):

The *DOM* object model relies on the fact to have loaded all data into memory. Even if you would find an implementation that does delay loading of the stuff delayed you still would run out of memory if the *DOM* api users traverse the whole *DOM* tree.

In effect you would save memory when you do `XMemorySavingXDocument`.Load("big.xml")` but the first XPath or LINQ query would still lead to an *OutOfMemoryException*. This is true if any of the queries does traverse the complete DOM tree. If you can ensure that this is never the case you could get away with such lazy DOM tree.

I do not know any such implementation but I doubt it would help in your case anyway. As you said a large number of DOM Api users will wade through the DOM tree touching all nodes and you get the OutOfMemoryException only a few ms later with such a solution.

The XML DOM object model does "unzip" the xml file into a in memory representation which consumes about 7 times more memory (x64) than the original file. For 32 bit it is still about a factor of 3.5.

The reason why the XML DOM model is so bloated is that each dom node knows it child, parent and attributes. This are object references for every DOM node which do cost you quite a lot.

A managed class object consumes at least 12/24 bytes per instance. Since each node pointer does add another 4/8 bytes (x86,x64) to the total memory consumption you are running out of memory quite quickly with a big xml file. See this [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2012/07/25/150301.aspx) for more infos about the .NET object sizes.

Since DOM is not a good idea for big XML files but your current architecture requires DOM I fear that you will need to abstract DOM away and replace it with an API that does extract (and potentially modify) the stuff you are interested in. In a big organization you can bring this topic up to the architects and present them as a major redesign with a must have prio.

If you are even more lucky to get a commitment from the architects and management then some outsourced programers in countries you never have been to get their next big backlog item to work on ;-).

To give you some numbers how much the data format does influence performance I did create a file with 1 million integers. I did use 3 different data formats

- Binary 40 MB
- ASCII Text File 80 MB (ddd\r\nddd\r\n...)
- Xml File 170 MB (*1*\r\n*2*....)

Then I did read them in a 64 bit process

- 0,1s Binary file via Memory Mapped File
- 0,5s BinaryReader
- 2,5s Text File
- 5,3s XmlReader (streaming)
- 8,6s XDocument.Load

The memory consumption was was flat at ~200 MB with the exception of XDocument.Load which did lead to a 1.2 GB memory peak. Your perf goal might be different but I would first convert the Xml stuff via a streaming XmlReader to a binary format which can be loaded much faster.

Comment: Well, even if you transverse the whole DOM, you only really need the point where the iterating pointer is to be held in memory at one time. Child/parent/etc. elements could be "hydrated" from disk when requested rather than being allocated all at once.

Comment: This sounds possible but it would be quite hard to arrive at a reasonable tradeoff between speed and memory consumption. I still do not think you will get around to change the approach how you access the data. DOM is an all in memory model. If the data does not fit into memory you need to become more selective with what you read. The used Apis need to reflect this or the users of the Api will still (wrongly) assume that they can query the file over and over again with little perf hit because all is already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an optimal solution, but in the past I've read in an XML files as strings and used regular expressions to break portions out into their own DOM objects.

Perhaps you could also use XPath? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath)